# Magento left side bar customization

Tags: magento

I have a magento site developed by someone else. I am now taking over the site. I am a new bee in magento. Someone please tell me how to customize or change the left sidebar of this page:

http://www.365zay.com/mobile-phones.html?brand=44

where will i find the code, and what is the file structure of Magento?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

go to admin/system/configuration - then on left bar click developer, -> on top left change current scope to Main Website-> On Debug Tab- Turn YES on both Template Path Hints & Add Block Names to Hints -> After that you we will be able to see path for your particular files on frontend.

It will be more better if you first follow, Magento Design & Userguide.

Comment: but on the debug tab the only option is "profiler". I don't find "Template Path Hints" and "Add Block Names to Hints"

Comment: yes you may be in the default config.just select the Main Website from top left then you can see the option Template Path Hints and Add Block Names.

Comment: now on frontend you can see the hints in red colour that which block is loaded from which file